# Помогите нажать на элемент в Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Я пишу программу на селениуме. Всё шло хорошо пока я не попал в такую ситуацию, что мне попался элемент на который я не знаю как оставить ссылку. Он находится в div class="wrap", а сам элемент выглядит так:

```
<a href="https://site.com/wp-admin/post-new.php" class="page-title-action">Добавить новую</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно понять как нужно искать:
Проще всего по CSS селектору

Потом нужно составить селектор:

```
div.wrap a.page-title-action
```

(Элемент `div` с классом `wrap` внутри которого элемент `a` с классом `page-title-action`)

Ну и на всем этом нам надо вызвать `click()`

Все вместе

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.your.site/")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.wrap a.page-title-action").click()
```